# rewrite rule failed to work when I moved on a newer Apache version (2.4)

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I had a Centos 5 VPS and moved on to Centos 7 with Apache 2.4. I don't know what was my earlier version of Apache on Centos 5 system, but I know that my Rewrite rule worked perfectly.

However when I moved to Apache 2.4 my old rewriting rule stopped working:

Old Rule:
`RewriteRule    ^(\/[^\.]*)$ /index.php?page=$1 [NC]`
Triggers this error in error log:

`AH00124: Request exceeded the limit of 10 internal redirects due to probable configuration error. Use 'LimitInternalRecursion' to increase the limit if necessary. Use 'LogLevel debug' to get a backtrace.
AH00124: Request exceeded the limit of 10 internal redirects due to probable configuration error. Use 'LimitInternalRecursion' to increase the limit if necessary. Use 'LogLevel debug' to get a backtrace.`

New Rule I tried which at least make my www.domainname.com to work:
`RewriteRule ^([^/]*)$ /index.php?page=$1 [NC]`

What is different on Apache 2.4 ? I couldn't find a clue neither here or on Google.

Comment: Well, certainly this will result in a rewriting loop but that has nothing to do with the http server version. You rewrite to a target that again matches the pattern you use. Since that rules _changes_ the target with each rewrite, always a new rewriting round is triggered. Endlessly... You need to add a `RewriteCond` that prevents requests to `index.php` getting rewritten...

Comment: Good. Thank you for the tip. One more question: how do you explain the fact it didn't need a RewriteCond till now?

Comment: Not really sure, I'd have to spend time on that or even test it... Certainly the old pattern should have avoided a loop due to the fact that it did not accept a dot (`.`) in the request, though that obviously is a pretty rude strategy... Maybe this is simply the effect of the notorious `MultiViews` directive... But anyway: the `RewriteCond` definitely does make sense...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add a RewriteCond that prevents requests to index.php getting rewritten. Two approaches come into mind:

1) only rewrite if the request does *not* target an existing physical file:

```
Options -MultiViews
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !-f
RewriteRule ^/?([^/]*)$ /index.php?page=$1 [END]
```

2) only rewrite if the request does not explicitly target the `/index.php` location:

```
Options -MultiViews
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/index\.php$
RewriteRule ^/?([^/]*)$ /index.php?page=$1 [END]
```

The leading `^/?` makes sure that this pattern will work in `.htaccess` style files *and* in the real http servers host configuration. That makes sense because:

A general hint: you should always prefer to place such rules inside the http servers host configuration instead of using `.htaccess` style files. Those files are notoriously error prone, hard to debug and they really slow down the server. They are only provided as a last option for situations where you do not have control over the host configuration (read: really cheap hosting service providers) or if you have an application that relies on writing its own rewrite rules (which is an obvious security nightmare).

Comment: Thank you for your answer and the extra tip. Fortunately I don't use .htaccess files :). Regarding the answer it was exactly what I needed. Please update this rule: *RewriteRule ^/?([^\]*)$ /index.php?page=$1 [END] * to *RewriteRule ^/?([^/]*)$ /index.php?page=$1 [END]* so others will see the exact corect answer. Thank you again. P.S. It's hard to notice, but one backslash is a slash. :)

Comment: @besciualex That modification of the rule does not make any sense, sorry. That pattern would only match a request URI consisting of a single letter...

Comment: But it didn't worked with a backslash. That's why I updated it.

Comment: @besciualex Ah, sorry, sure, changed that backslash into a forward slash. No idea where that came from, got a brand new keyboard layout, maybe that's the cause ;-) Fixed that, thanks again. My reply referred to the star operator (`*`) your suggestion also removes which does not make sense in my eyes.

Comment: Aaa! My bad! It's a special character and I haven't escaped it inside the comment above.